# Timeout para execução de query

Tags: php

Tenho uma simples função:

```
$sql_em = " INSERT INTO tabela (`campo1`, `campo2`) VALUES ({$c1}, {$c2}) ";
$em_obj = new Mysqli($this -> host, $this -> db_user, $this -> db_pass, $this -> db_name);

$em_obj -> query($sql_em);
```

Gostaria de setar um `timeout` para a execução da `query` (`$em_obj -> query($sql_em)`).

Isso é possível ? Caso sim, tem retorno do erro por timeout ?

Comment: Nunca vi algo assim com o php. Eles querem deixar o fluxo do programa mais rápido o timeout interfere muito no fluxo do script talvez a melhor forma de se fazer isso é controlando essas queries no lado cliente com javascript

Comment: @AtilaSilva o problema é que eu executo essa mesma query vindo de vários lugares, com o mesmo insert, mas alguns deles, travam na query. Eu precisava disso para debug.

Comment: entendo.  Já tentou verificar o consumo de memória da operação?

Comment: Eu até resolvi para falar verdade, era um erro no objeto com commit e outro com rollback, mas deixei a pergunta para ver se existe...

Answer (score -2):

Uma ideia de como pode fazer:

Crie um arquivo que será responsável pela query sozinho, como se fosse agendar uma tarefa.

No arquivo principal, onde você executa isso hoje, ele não fará nada além de passar a responsabilidade para o arquivo novo.

Uma das forma de fazer:

`shell_exec('curl "http://localhost/executaquery.php?dados=" >> /dev/null &' )`

Isso faz com que o script rode, passe a tarefa, não aguarde retorno e continue livre.

No seu executaquery.php você pode usar o `sleep()` para o script rodar seu `timeout`, ele pode demorar o quanto quiser, o processo anterior não depende disso mais.

Isso é apenas uma forma, talvez até um pouco porca, de fazer. Vai resolver seu problema e abrir sua mente para processos mais distribuídos.

O ideal neste caso, é você entender um pouco sobre crontab, para aprender formas de agendar tarefas na aplicação. Isso te ajudará a ter filas para quaisquer etapas do seu processo.

Um exemplo prático seria você querer fazer centenas de queries ao mesmo tempo, sem esperar a anterior ser resolvida.

Nota que o `&` faz com que o processo rode em background no sistema operacional, ou seja, vai empilhar varios processos que serão resolvidos um a um.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
  shell_exec('php query.php &');
}
```

Eu falei um pouco disso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/289437/21836).

Comment: Então, mas aí eu não tenho um retorno do porque do timeout, eu só iria "matar" o processamento do PHP e não da query correto !?

Comment: Correto, apenas do PHP. Agora entendi sua pergunta por outro angulo, muito boa pergunta. Vou responder em breve

Comment: Seu problema parece estranho, dê uma olhada nestes dois conteudos por favor. Vamos tentar entender e ai atualizamos a resposta para ajudar os proximos.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836623/getting-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-even-though-im

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415905/how-to-set-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-mysql-query

Answer (score -2):

O php não tem uma função de timeout, o mas próximo disso é a função `sleep`.

A função `sleep` atrasa a execução do script:

```
int sleep ( int $seconds )
```

Exemplo:

```
$sql_em = " INSERT INTO tabela (`campo1`, `campo2`) VALUES ({$c1}, {$c2}) ";
$em_obj = new Mysqli($this -> host, $this -> db_user, $this -> db_pass, $this -> db_name);

sleep(10);
$em_obj -> query($sql_em);
```

Neste exemplo, a linha `$em_obj -> query($sql_em);` será executada após 10 segundos.

Comment: Mas eu não quero "atrasar" o processamento, eu queria setar um tempo de timeout, igual o `set_time_limit(120)` do php, e se der um retorno do erro, exemplo: (encerrado por timeout).